# HttpModule Filter_OnTransformString causes some static files to fail (ie css, js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I have an HttpModule to analysis and monitoring of web sites. In this HttpModule, it makes use of a response filter to to modify response body and insert a fragment of code to load javascript code into text/html content.

```
private string Filter_OnTransformString(string output)
{
    Logger.Info("Filter_OnTransformString", "Enter method for " + Request.RawUrl);

    if (Response.ContentType != "text/html")
    {
        Logger.Info("Filter_OnTransformString", "Exiting for " + Response.ContentType + " MIME type for " + Request.RawUrl);
        return output;
    }

    if (output != null)
    {
        var pos = output.IndexOf("</body>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        Logger.Verbose("Filter_OnTransformString", "pos (of closing </body>) == " + pos);

        if (pos > -1)
        {
            var left = output.Substring(0, pos);
            var right = output.Substring(pos);

            output = left + "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/heartbeat.axd/script\"></script>" + right;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.Warning("Filter_OnTransformString", "output == null for " + Request.RawUrl);
    }

    Logger.Info("Filter_OnTransformString", "Exit method for " + Request.RawUrl);

    return output;
}
```

Looking at the network traffic in the Chrome DevTools, I see that bootstrap.css, jquery-ui.min.css, jquery-3.1.1.js, and respond.js all failed.

[image]

Yet, other CSS and JS files came down just fine. For example, here is the log file output for `modernizr-2.8.3.js` followed by the log file output for `jquery-3.1.1.js`.

```
11:19:31.1695   Info    Filter_OnTransformString    Enter method for /Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js
11:19:31.1695   Info    Filter_OnTransformString    Exiting for application/javascript MIME type for /Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js


11:19:31.5914   Info    Filter_OnTransformString    Enter method for /Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js
11:19:31.5914   Info    Filter_OnTransformString    Exiting for application/javascript MIME type for /Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js
```

Is there something critical I'm missing here?

**Update:**

At the moment, I've coded around the issue like this:

```
if (!Request.RawUrl.EndsWithAny(new[] { ".css", ".js" }, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Logger.Verbose("Application_BeginRequest", "Attaching Response.Filter to " + Request.RawUrl);
    ResponseFilterStream filter = new ResponseFilterStream(Response.Filter);
    filter.TransformString += Filter_OnTransformString;
    Response.Filter = filter;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more time working around the problem, I checked the Application log on the server. I found the culprit.

The HttpModule is throwing an unhandled exception and that is what's causing the request to simply fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect for set `output` var:

```
output = left + "<script type="text/javascript" src="/heartbeat.axd/script"></script>" + right;
```

the correct form to concatenate is:

```
output = left + "<script type='text/javascript' src='/heartbeat.axd/script'></script>" + right;
```

Probably this will generate an exception and not load your static files.

Comment: Good catch, though it's a simplification of the current code which pulls the `<script ...>` fragment from an embedded resource file.

Comment: One last note, this answer doesn't actually address the problem in question. That bit of script injection loads the heartbeat.axd/script which is loading just fine.